# How to enforce a belong_to only if the user is of a certain type (using Enum, Mongoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, mongoid4

I'm using Mongoid and Mongoid-Enum.

Here's my `User` model snippet:

```
enum :role, [:admin, :artist, :customer], :validate => true, :default => :admin
```

For my `Voice` model I wrote a test (using an example in Mongoid-rspec website) such as:

```
it { is_expected.to belong_to(:artist).of_type(User) }
```

And in my `Voice` model:

```
belongs_to :users
```

However I can't get the test to pass. How do I to enforce that the user is of specific type (artist, through enum)?

Comment: firs of all `belongs_to :users` seems incorrect as belongs_to is used for to_one relation

Comment: And what would you suggest to enforce this relationship?

Comment: Am I correct that you want an Actor to has only one Voice?

Comment: That is correct! The Voice model might have many files (lets say samples of the same voice speaking different languages, etc) but that's another topic.